# Added a file to gitignore now it gets deleted when I pull from another machine

Tags: git

when I add that file to gitignore it stays ignored on the machine I committed from, but it gets deleted on the origin.
How do I stop tracking/ignoring a file without it being actually deleted on origin?

Comment: Hi Reem Osama! Welcome :) Please provide the commands you have tried - by edition your question - including the output of `git status`. So that users can help find a solution to your question. Currently it may be challenging for users determine your issue and current git state.

Comment: That's not how Git works, but there's likely a better solution. What is the specific use case? Are you trying to overwrite a config file? And specifically what is "origin" here? A centralized Git server like GitHub? A server where you're trying to run the code? Something else?

Comment: You did not *just* add the file to `.gitignore`. You also *removed the file*. That is, between commit P (parent) and C (child), the difference—or a difference—is "remove the file". Whenever Git switches from P to C, Git will remove the file. Now, *you personally* sidestepped this removal in *your* checkout *at the one time you did this manually*. But it will always happen in every Git repository when moving from P to C, *unless* whoever is doing the moving carefully sidesteps the removal like you did.